# Selecting default option in PHP dropdown list

Tags: php, html, html-select

This is likely a lot simpler than I'm thinking but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have the following code that's part of a image results list:

```
<option value="30" <?php echo ($_SESSION['results']== 30) ?  'selected' : ''; ?>>30</option>
        <option value="40" <?php echo ($_SESSION['results']== 40) ?  'selected' : ''; ?>>40</option>
        <option value="50" <?php echo ($_SESSION['results']== 50) ?  'selected' : ''; ?>>50</option>
        <option value="60" <?php echo ($_SESSION['results']== 60) ?  'selected' : ''; ?>>60</option>
        <option value="70" <?php echo ($_SESSION['results']== 70) ?  'selected' : ''; ?>>70</option>
        <option value="80" <?php echo ($_SESSION['results']== 80) ?  'selected' : ''; ?>>80</option>
        <option value="90" <?php echo ($_SESSION['results']== 90) ?  'selected' : ''; ?>>90</option>
```

The default of course is 40 results but I want the default to be 80. How do I make it so 80 is automatically selected by default

Comment: "The default of course is 40"  It is?  Not based on what I'm seeing.

Comment: Somewhere before the code you posted the value of `$_SESSION['results']` is getting set. It is there that the 40 is likely being set and where you need to make the change. As Patrick said, nothing in what you posted is defaulting to 40.

Comment: the only thing I see is this: $_SESSION['results'] = (!isset($_SESSION['results']) ? $_SESSION['results'] : (isset($_GET['results']) ? $_GET['results'] : $_SESSION['results']));

Comment: Then it's further back ... in whatever calls the code where this code resides. Something is setting that session value in the URL when calling this code.

Comment: I don't think that ternary statement is doing what you think it is.  You'd be better off using if/else statements to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way to do this would be:

```
<?php
session_start();  //Start session

$_SESSION['results'] = $_SESSION['results'] ? $_SESSION['results'] : 80;   //Check and set the session variable else default it to 80

$numbers = [30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90];   //Initialize your array

?>
<select name="test">
    <?php
    foreach ($numbers as $num) {      //Loop through the array and populate your select box.
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $num; ?>" <?php echo ($_SESSION['results'] == $num) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>><?php echo $num; ?></option>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```